# Math Error in Bezier curve

Tags: math, lua, bezier

I'm trying to get plots to generate a cubic *Bezier Curve*, and I've managed to be able to generate linear and quad easily, but I keep getting an error with my cubic formula,

Linear formula:`x = (1-t)*(p0x + (t * p1x))`
quad formula:`x = (1-t)^2 * p0x + 2*(1-t) * t * p1x + t^2 * p2x`
cubic formula:`x = (1–t)^3 * p0x + 3*(1–t)^2 * t * p1x + 3*(1–t)*t^2 * p2x + t^3 * p3x`

Though the quad and cubic formula are very similar, the cubic errors "')' expected near '–'". How can this be fixed?

I'm programming this in Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtraction signs in your cubic formula aren't plain `-`:

```
>>> s = """
... linear formula: `x = (1-t)*(p0x + (t * p1x))`
... quad formula: `x = (1-t)^2 * p0x + 2*(1-t) * t * p1x + t^2 * p2x`
... cubic formula: `x = (1–t)^3 * p0x + 3*(1–t)^2 * t * p1x + 3*(1–t)*t^2 * p2x + t^3 * p3x`
... 
... """
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     print repr(line)
... 
''
'linear formula: `x = (1-t)*(p0x + (t * p1x))`'
'quad formula: `x = (1-t)^2 * p0x + 2*(1-t) * t * p1x + t^2 * p2x`'
'cubic formula: `x = (1\xe2\x80\x93t)^3 * p0x + 3*(1\xe2\x80\x93t)^2 * t * p1x + 3*(1\xe2\x80\x93t)*t^2 * p2x + t^3 * p3x`'
''
```

They're actually U+2013 `–`, which is EN DASH.  Fix those and it should be fine.

Comment: Good catch. Reminded me of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726924/iconv-library-on-mac-os-x-strange-behavior.